# How to retrieve "n" lines from a text?

Tags: python, parsing, text, line, fastq

I am working with a FastQ file which is a text file with different elements in every 4 lines. I am trying to search for a certain string in a line and retrieve that line with the following three lines. But I am not sure how to do that.
So far, I am only able to retrieve the target line, but not the following three.
Supposing that my target line has a "XXXX" as part of the string, a fragment of my code is as follows:

```
with open (x, 'rt') as myfile:   
    for line in myfile:

        if re.findall ('.+XXXX.+', line):
            target.write (line)
            count_target = count_target + 1

        else:
            leftover.write (line)
            count_left = count_left + 1
```

How could I improve my code to get the four consecutive lines everytime it founds "XXXX"?

Answer (score 1):

Once you found your line, call `next(myfile)` 3 times:

```
with open (x, 'rt') as myfile:   
    for line in myfile:

        if re.findall ('.+XXXX.+', line):
            target.write (line)
            for i in range(3):
                target.write(next(myfile))
```

Comment: You can also zip the current iterator with `range(4)` and use a `for` loop

Comment: Thank you so much Hai Vu. So simple and so useful!